# Not able to click on checkbox using selenium in Python,Error- selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on the checkbox on a website, getting below error, please suggest.

Error I am getting is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input id="privacy_policy" type="checkbox" name="user[privacy_policy]" class="" value="0"> is not clickable at point (674, 592). Other element would receive the click: <p class="cookieinfo-text">...</p>
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.91)
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options =webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

chromedriver_path = r'C:\Users\LENOVO\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))

driver.get('https://register.whirlpool.com/en-us/registration')
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(2)
# Find and fill the form fields
model_field = driver.find_element('id', 'model')

time.sleep(2)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# checkbox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("id", "privacy_policy")))
# checkbox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("XPATH", "//*[@id='privacy_policy']")))
time.sleep(3)
checkbox = driver.find_element("id","privacy_policy")
time.sleep(3)
checkbox.click()
var1= driver.find_element("id","privacy_policy").is_selected()
print(var1)
time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to click on the `checkbox`:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://register.whirlpool.com/en-us/registration')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'privacy_policy')))

driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('privacy_policy').click();")
time.sleep(2)
var1 = driver.find_element(By.ID, "privacy_policy").is_selected()
print(var1)
```

output:

```
True
```

You can also cross-check by simply running the javascript query `document.getElementById('privacy_policy').click()` on the `Console` of the page and you'll see that it indeed performs the click on the desired `checkbox`.

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice the exception, selenium is not able to click `<input>` element, and it clearly says the reason, other element will receive the click.

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <input id="privacy_policy" is not clickable at point (759, 688). Other element would receive the click: <label for="privacy_policy">...</label>
  (Session info: chrome=113.0.5672.129)
```

**SOLUTION:** Just click on that other element, which is the `<label>` wrapping the `<input>`.

So change your locator from:

```
checkbox = driver.find_element("id","privacy_policy")
```

To:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='privacy_policy']"))).click()
```

**Full Working code:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://register.whirlpool.com/en-us/registration')
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# below line click on the Accept cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Okay, Got It']"))).click()
# below line clicks on the <label> element of the checkbox
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='privacy_policy']"))).click()

var1 = driver.find_element("id", "privacy_policy").is_selected()
print(var1)
time.sleep(10)
```

**Console:**

```
True
```

**Result:**

[image]

**NOTE:** Avoid using JS to perform actions as much as you can. It should be used as a last resort.